# Errores al instalar VS Community 2015. De ser necesario corregirlos ¿Como solucionar estos errores?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Al terminar de instalar VS, me generó estos errores, ¿que tan necesario es corregirlos, para trabajar con C# y .NET ? y ¿Como se pueden corregir?
Actualmente como se haya instalado VS, no inicia el programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías subir el archivo de registro a http://pastebin.com/ para poder visualizar los errores que tuviste

Comment: si ya se instalo y el equipo se reinició, ¿comó puedo ir a ese registro?

Comment: cuanto es el tamañano de los archivos `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140.dll` y `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll`

Comment: ¿Haz intentado volver a reinstalarlo?, como reparar la anterior instalación.

Comment: voy a reinstalar, porque en ese archivo tiene caracteres diferentes, nada de error

Comment: disculpe, ¿como se puede des instalar todo lo instalado de VS?

Comment: En la carpeta de instalación `vs_community.exe /uninstall /force`

Comment: no encuentro esas carpetas,